# How can I log all changes to Ubuntus packaging system?

Tags: logging, ubuntu, scripting, apt

I have an ubuntu box and I want to get/log all changes to the packaging system (apt/dpkg) so I can reproduce them on an other machine.

My goal is to extract an update script to reproduce the same configuration on a different machine.

So I either want the executed commands or the following information:

- order of changes
- package name
- version
- modification (install, remove, reconfigure etc.)
- parameters used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is already there. Look into `/var/log/apt/history.log*` and you see all you need.

But if you want to see all installed packages you can look into `dpkg --get-selections`. To replay these selections you can use `dpkg --get-selections`. More information about that can be found with `man dpkg`.